# Vendor Framework A is containing the same Framework B than the Project Pods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, mbprogresshud

Ok, so, I have some issues between [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) (Pod) and ([Scandit](http://www.scandit.com)) (Vendor Framework).

In fact I was using MBProgressHUB from Pods before and it was working really well.

But after installing Scandit, I have the following error message :

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FApp'
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_MBBarProgressView in:
    /Users/nickName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-gqhyrdejqjmsbfgnidtyhwodtfnp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libMBProgressHUD.a(MBProgressHUD.o)
    /Users/nickName/Projects/Git/appDirectory/ScanditBarcodeScanner.framework/ScanditBarcodeScanner(SCMBProgressHUD.o)

... 10 times ...

duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MBRoundProgressView._annular in:
    /Users/nickName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-gqhyrdejqjmsbfgnidtyhwodtfnp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libMBProgressHUD.a(MBProgressHUD.o)
    /Users/nickName/Projects/Git/appDirectory/ScanditBarcodeScanner.framework/ScanditBarcodeScanner(SCMBProgressHUD.o)
ld: 12 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The deduction is pretty simple; Scandit is using MBProgressHUD too... The problem is; I need to use MBProgressHUD on my project but I can't use it with Pods (conflict).

There is a way to use the MBProgress Framework contained by Scandit or can I use a trick to handle the error ?

Any answer will be very appreciate.

Comment: Send a message to the Scandit developer and point out the issue being caused by their library. In the meantime, drop your use of `MBProgressHUD` and use `SCMBProgressHUD` instead.

Comment: I am having the same problems. Have you found out a solution yet?

Comment: Actually yes, I have simply reported the issue to the framework creators, and they solve it :)